# MPlayer won't send audio output to bluetooth headset

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, mplayer, headset

This is the first time I try to pair a bluetooth device on Ubuntu.  This is an up-to-date 18.04, and the device is an Andoer LH-811.

`blueman-applet` is detecting the headset and pairing successfully, but after pairing the audio still ouputs through the laptop speakers.

It appears from `blueman-manager` that the device is connected as *Serial port* even when I choose *Synchronie audio* (French equivalent to *Audio sink*, I guess ?) or *Handsfree*, and nothing happens when I change it back to these options.

Furthermore, I can't change the profile to HSP/HFP : I get the error

> Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit

On `pavucontrol` I can change the volume of the headset, and I *hear* the test sound of the volume in the headset, but I can't seem to select the headset as default output, even playing with the "set as alternative" buttons.

### Update

Figured it works with `aplay` and `firefox`, so it seems to be an `mplayer` issue.  I tried `mplayer -ao pulse movie.avi` without success, and `mplayer -ao alsa:device=bluetooth` with an `.asoundrc` containing `pcm.bluetooth { type bluetooth }`, as suggested elsewhere, didn't help either.

**How do I make `mplayer` audio output through the bluetooth headset ?**

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround [on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458874/26952) : in the first panel (*Lecture* in French) of `pavucontrol`

> there is a button to connect a sound source such as mplayer to a particular output device

Obviously a better way would to have PulseAudio switch automatically to the external audio.  It seems a common issue (see e.g. [Make PulseAudio prefer external audio device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113704) or [Automatically change Sound Input Output device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158241/)), and proposed solutions (loading `module-switch-on-connect`) didn't seem to help in my case.