# Make PulseAudio switch to headphones when inserted

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, pulseaudio, jack, audio-jack

I have a Dell Latitude 3540 with Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. Possibly similar to [Make PulseAudio prefer external audio device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113704/make-pulseaudio-prefer-external-audio-device) and [Internal microphone doesn't work when using headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218136/internal-microphone-doesnt-work-when-using-headphones),  I bought a pair of earbuds with microphone, plugged them in, and... nothing.  So then I went into Mixer settings (pavucontrol-qt) and selected the `Headphones (unplugged)` and presto, they work just fine. Still says they are unplugged though. Tried plugging them in several more times, but they were never auto-detected. They work, but I must manually pick `Headphones (unplugged)` when inserted, and reset to `Speakers` when removed.

Looking for a solution to auto-detect, I came across the linked articles, which Sam's answer says to add `load-module module-switch-on-connect` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. That line is already in there, and the file exists as `/usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules/module-switch-on-connect.so` :

```
### Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.endif
```

Now this isn't an audio device being inserted, just a pair of headphones, so may not apply. PulseAudio should be able to detect and switch on headphones being inserted... any idea why it's not, and how to correct it?

Note: One thing I forgot to mention, I have `jack`, jackd1 and jackd2 installed and working well to route signals. No issues with jack and it is not running.

Comment: Is **module-switch-on-port-available** loaded? Check with `pactl list short modules`.

Comment: Yes it is loaded according to `pactl`.